# Fetch having CORS issue with external API in React

Tags: reactjs, cors

I'm getting the following error in the screenshot when I'm trying to use fetch with basic auth and external API:

[image]

**Fetch method**

```
const fetchBusVendors = async () => {
        const url = 'https://externalapi.com'
        const username = 'test'
        const password = 'test'

        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

        const res = await fetch(url, {
            headers: headers
        });

        const data = await res.json();

        return data;
    };
```

The API is an external API that has a different domain/origin from my localhost.

Currently I'm only using ReactJS as the frontend and there's no backend server setup like Express.js. With this CORS issue, does that mean I must setup a backend server in order to use an external API with basic auth? What's the optimal solution that will work in production also and not just using a method like setting up a proxy server in development only?

I don't have this issue if the external API that I'm using to fetch doesn't require a basic auth.

Comment: need to enable CORS from BACKend side to resolved issue

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1:** If you want access the API, CORS settings needs to be enable in the API side to access from your React application.

**Option 2:**  Use proxy in your package.json file in React Application(It is only for development). If your API is http://localhost:8005/users/ then add this in your package.json file "proxy": "http://localhost:8005/" and access the api as follows,

```
const res = await fetch("users/", {
    headers: headers
 });
```

Comment: If you use `no-cors` header `Authorization` won't send

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).